# Excel/VB/HTML Format Table Cells based on value

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I am trying to format the background color of a td imbedded in my VB code based off the value of the cell from Excel. My codes purpose is to send an email with a html table, and I want to be able to highlight cells in the HTML table that are certain values.

This is a basic look at the table I'm creating within VB, minus the bgcolor code.

```
"<table style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial; width=auto>" & _
            "<tr >" & _
                "<td>Title</td>" & _
                "<td align=right>" & FormatPercent(("I16"), 0) & "</td> " & _
                "<td align=right>" & FormatPercent(("J16"), 0) & "</td> " & _
            "</tr>" & _
"</table>"
```

What I'm trying to do is format a  to give it a bgcolor of either green >=98%, blue >=95% & <98% else red. I have roughly 24 different cells and I want a dynamic color that changes itself based off the content of the cell.

I've done this manually before, creating a string for every single cell; however, I feel this is extremely inefficient and there is probably a better way to do this.

I an not sure if there is a way I can insert an excel value into my table and keep the formatting of the cell and use a format condition within excel to determine colors. I've tried looking this up but could not find anything to define this.

If there is a way to do something like:

```
If <td> value >= 0.98 then
    color=green
elseif <td> value > 0.95 then
    color = blue
else
    color = red
End if
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

*Edit 1: Didn't realise when I typed "< td>", it was not appearing. Substituted it for the word "cell".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in HTML, however you can use JavaScript to dynamically modify your HTML DOM:

```js
let cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); // Get cells

Array.from(cells).forEach(cell => { // For each cell
  let value = Number.parseFloat(cell.innerHTML); // Parse the value of the cell
  if (value >= 0.98) { // Check the value
    cell.style.backgroundColor="green"; // Modify the cell's CSS
  } else if (value >= 0.9) {
    cell.style.backgroundColor="blue";
  } else cell.style.backgroundColor="red";
});
```

```html
<table style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial; width=auto>
            <tbody>
            <tr id="row">
                <td>0.95</td>
                <td>0.99</td>
                <td>0.67</td>
                <td>0.48</td>
                <td>0.93</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```